# How to keep record of no of elements been drag and drop

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I have 4 apples and 4 oranges on screen and 2 basket,one for each.I am dragging apple and oranges into their respective basket succesfuuly.I want a next screen button to appear after all items are placed in the basket.

How to count that all items are placed in their basket?
        :  My Code

```
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    apple.center = location;

   if (apple.center.x == 233 || apple.center.y == 368)
   {
    apple.hidden = YES;
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 2 `int` counters: `numberOfApplesInBasket` and `numberOfOrangesInBasket`.

```
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
apple.center = location;

if (apple.center.x == 233 || apple.center.y == 368)
{
  apple.hidden = YES;
  numberOfApplesInBasket += 1;
  if (numberOfApplesInBasket == 4 && numberOfOrangesInBasket == 4) {
    // Do your thing
  }
}
```

Comment: Thnx,i will try and let you know :)